# I cant access my mysql server hosted on azure from remote

Tags: mysql, azure, ubuntu, azure-virtual-machine

Good evening all, i have set up an azure server with ubuntu server and have installed MySQL with some python code I need to run , I have turned off the firewall on Ubuntu and setup port forward on azure and i still can not connect to MySQL from my pc using workbench, I installed PHPMyAdmin as well and I was not able to connect to that either, I am not sure what else I can try, I have started setting up a new server on a local pc but I would it on the cloud

Comment: Have you enabled 3306 port on Network security group of your VM network interface ? If not , pls enable it .You can check it on your VM =>Networking=>Inbound port rules. For details about Network security group , just refer to this doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview

Comment: yep sure have here is a link to the ports https://ibb.co/0ZQJhLb

Comment: Hi @ADBY , how's going ? has your issue been solved ?

Comment: Hi @ADBY, if my answer is helpful for you, pls mark it as an answer. If you mark helpful answers each time, more people will be glad to assist you

Answer (score 0):

I created a Linux (ubuntu 18.04) VM ,set up a mysql on it and access it on my local successfully. This is my steps below :

1.Enable 3306 port on Azure portal :

[image]

2.Connect to Azure VM , and run command below to install mysql :

```
sudo -i 
apt install mysql-server
```

3.After your mysql is installed , modify “bind-address” directive in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf , modify 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 to make sure your mysql server will listening on all your VM's ips :

```
vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

[image]

save your modify and restart your mysql server :

```
systemctl restart mysql
```

This time , can ping 3306 port of my vm successfully : 
[image]

*If your mysql server is running on your VM successfully , but you can not ping it,if the error info is timeout , pls check your firewall settings , if the error info is remote server refused your request , this means there is no service listening on 3306 port.*

4.Create a user on mysql so that we can use this account connect to mysql from local:

```
CREATE USER 'stan'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123456';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'stan'@'%'  WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

[image]

Well , try to connect to mysql from local using navicat :

[image]

Connect to mysql on Azure Linux VM from local successfully : 
[image]

Hope it helps .